# How do I login an existing user with Django's authentication system?

Tags: python, django

```
def sign_in(request):
    #we need to handle all the data that was just typed, we'll add a condition for that
    form = NameForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save()
        post.save()
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        #auth = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        # If the username and password are provided try to auth them
        if username and password:
            print username, password
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            # if it authenticates successfully, check if the user is not an admin, log them in
            if user:
                if not user.is_staff:
                    login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('success')
    else:
        form = NameForm()
    return render(request, 'checkin/sign_in_new.html', {'form': form})
```

**EDIT**: Changed code to work with backend. Added `user.is_staff` but it still won't return any web page, it just stays on the same one

`models.py`:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

# Create your models here.

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField("What is your ID?", max_length=100, null=True)
    #pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    id_text = models.CharField("", max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

`forms.py`:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Question

#put the form here

class NameForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['question_text', 'id_text']

class IdForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['id_text']
```

**Edit 2** These are my model and form files, should these not effect the naming of certain parameters in my backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django authentication system.

I think you are familiar with saving the user data with models
you can use the authentication backend for solving this problem please refer following steps. create custom backends. in project root 
backends/staff_backends.py

```
from project_app_path.staffs.models import MODEL_NAME
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class StaffBackend:
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):

        try:
            user = MODEL_NAME.objects.get(username=username)
            if check_password(password, user.password):
                return user
            else:
                return None
        except MODEL_NAME.DoesNotExist:
            return None
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return MODEL_NAME.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except MODEL_NAME.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Include the backends with project settings.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [ 

'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
'backends.staff_backends.StaffBackend',

]
```

in views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login ,logout

def any_view(request):
    rg = request.POST.get
    username = rg('username')
    password = rg('password')
    if username and password:
        print username,password
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user:
            if not user.is_staff:
                login(request,user)
            ### Redirect where you want , you can use this code in to you  signupage also.
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for this! I put it all into my project but I'm having an issue, when I submit the form nothing happens. It doesn't load any page that I've redirected to

Comment: I think the problem is that it's not loading the custom backend, because when I try to login to the `admin` website I'm getting and Import Error telling me `No module named backends.staff_backends`. My PROJECT name is `website`, that's where I put `backends`. So I have `/website/backends/staff_backends.py` just to be clear it needs to be in my project root and not my app folder right?

Comment: create a folder inside your project root directory called backends please make sure you have added __init__.py file inside the directory, then create staff_backends.py and put the codes inside the file, then mention the backends configs in settings.py file.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply, I added the init.py file. Which got the admin site working, I'm still having the same issue with the views.py though. It won't load another page. Check my edited post

Comment: I also added my `models.py` and `forms.py` files, should the names of my models/fields effect the naming of certain parameters in `backends.py`? Like `(username=username` for example?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it, and it works... but I create users automatically, so no form input, but you should get the idea:

```
            user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=user_email, email=user_email)

            if created:
                secret = str(uuid4())
                user.set_password(secret)
                user.save()

            user = User.objects.get(username=user_email)
            user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
            login(request, user)
```

so for you, you could probably just use `User.objects.get_or_create`... instead of `create_user`

and you would obviously have to add the auth step.

Comment: Okay thanks I'll give this a try, can you explain `(username=user_email, email=user_email)`? What parameters should I be using?

Comment: @Amon So, in my case, I am automatically creating Django users from another database/app. `user_email` comes from that. In your case you want to use the `username` that your user inputs to `get_or_create` the `User`. The way `get_or_create` works, it first looks for a `User` that matches the arguments, and if one does not exist, it creates it, with those properties. So you want `User.get_or_create(username = username)`